# Add if not exists or retrieve an entity in another entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is my problem : I have 2 entities named "Brand" and "Element". Each elements are related to a unique brand.

**Brand entity**

```
/**
* Brand
*
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\BrandRepository")
*/

class Brand
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="model", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $model;
```

**Element entity**

```
/**
 * Element
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\ElementRepository")
 */

class Element
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="serial", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $serial;

    ... others properties ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $brand;
```

I created a single Element form which integrated the Brand form :

```
// src/Acme/AcmeBundle/Form/ElementType.php

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('brand', new BrandType())
        ->add('mac')
        ->add('ip')
    ;
}
```

It works perfectly, but each new elements add a new brand, so I can have duplicates in my table (the brands 2 and 4 for example) :

```
-+--------+----------+-------+
 | ID | name |      model    |
-+--------+----------+-------+
 | 1  | Dell |  Inspiron 14  |
-+--------+----------+-------+
 | 2  | Dell |  Inspiron 15  |
-+--------+----------+-------+
 | 3  | Acer |   Aspire E    |
-+--------+----------+-------+
 | 4  | Dell |  Inspiron 15  |
-+--------+----------+-------+
 | .  |  ..  |      ...      |
-+--------+----------+-------+
```

When adding a new element, how to retrieve a registered brand (and mapped the element with it) instead of adding a new brand please ?

I thought about calling the EntityManager (search in Brand if the couple "name+model" exists, and if it's the case return this object) in a PrePersist function, but according other people it's not a good solution.

**Edit**

Here is the solution I used :

```
// src/Acme/AcmeBundle/Controller/AcmeController.php

public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Element();
    $form = $this->createForm(...);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $brand = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository('AcmeAcmeBundle:Brand')
               ->findOneBy(array(
                   'name' => $entity->getBrand()->getName(),
                   'model' => $entity->getBrand()->getModel()
                ));
        if($brand)
            $entity->setBrand($brand);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        // Redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the entire code where you are persisting a new Brand? Seems like should be required to query the db in order to search for duplicateds.

Comment: Pfff... thank you manix ! I thought it was required to use the PrePersist event, but it works perfectly through the controller :)

Comment: Let me show it a little bit..

Comment: Ops... I did not see your edited question/answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before persist any entity, you could trigger it as:

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('Brand')->findOneBy([
        'model' => $model, 
        'name' => $name
    ]);

    if ($entity == null)
    {
        //no brand found. So, persist the new one:
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        $element->setBrand($theNewBrand);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This feels like something one might do with a [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). However, I don't think that approach is applicable in this case because two field values (brand name and model) have to be filled in independently before it is possible to determine whether an existing brand applies.

Therefore in my opinion the most obvious solution, whilst not apparently elegant, is simply to check and if necessary update the brand object when the form is submitted, before the new Element is persisted (flushed) to the database (for code detail see answer by @manix, who posted whilst I was writing this!). This logic would be executed from the controller, either directly or indirectly if you are handling your business logic in a service(s).

Another approach typically used in this situation is to pre-populate the database with all the available brand names and models and provide drop-down lists from which the user selects. In this case ajax must be used to populate the model list when the brand name is changed. If it is important that all elements related to a particular brand can be located then this approach prevents duplication of brands as a result of typos.